# Sharepoint Individual Folder Permissions

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions

We are looking to integrate over to OneDrive for Businesss / Sharepoint.

We basically want to assign the documents and folders within the SharePoint documents folder individual permissions.

As the example shows below we would like 'Management' to access everything. 
'Accounts Team' to be able to access everything BUT the management folder. 
'Staff Team' only able to access documents within the root folder and the staff folder.
For example the image below;
[image: Example]

If someone could explain how exacty this can be done, that would be great.

Comment: You may want to reconsider your information architecture. Everyone in the group will still have access to things like the calendar and threaded conversions. Creating specifically scoped groups with people having multiple group memberships or adding differently secured libraries to a single group may make things easier down the road.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you hover over a folder, you'll notice ellipsis (`...`) appearing to the right of name.

Click on it, then `Share`, `Shared with` and `Advanced`.

By default permissions are inherited from parent. You need to click on `Stop inheriting permissions` on the ribbon to break this inheritance.

Now you can clear existing permissions and assign new ones according to your requirements.